# Get data from key categories in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these documents:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk?pretty" -d'
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
{"id_product":"1", "categories":[1,2] }
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
{"id_product":"2", "categories":[25,28] }
```

I need to get categories only.
Can I get an output similar to this?

```
[1,2,25,28]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no way to tell ES to return only `categories`, but you might use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation) in order to extract all categories that search context have.

Example:

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs":{
    "byCategory":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "categories"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return something like:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "byCategory": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 25,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 28,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, now you can iterate through `buckets.key` to extract all categories that are present on search.